# What Blur Algorithm Does Flash Use Internally In Their Blur Filter

Tags: javascript, algorithm, actionscript-3, flash, blur

I'm trying to convert something written in AS3 to JavaScript and the AS3 application uses Flash's built in [Blur Filter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/BlurFilter.html)

Does anyone know what blurring algorithm this used or how to replicate it in JavaScript?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It is a [Gaussian](http://Gaussian%20blur) style blur like they say in their documentation:

> When the quality property is set to high, it approximates a Gaussian
>   blur filter

It is highly optimized version of a style of Gaussian filter/Weierstrass transform, especially when using power of 2 x/y offsets, as you can apply it in real-time to video, so you are not going to get the exact result in a non-Flash app, but you can get **really** close and no one is going to know the difference.

There are **many** ways to do a Gaussian blur in html/css/javascript. There are methods via fancy drop-shadowing techniques in CSS, using an HTML5 Canvas and applying custom filters, javascript processing of bitmap via byte arrays, etc... some with cross-browser based limitations, some with CPU processing issues, etc.. google/bing is your friend for searching for different techniques people have already developed and the pros and cons they have encountered.

I grabbed the following one for a quick HTML5 project:

> Mario Klingemann has created a fast implementation of an “almost
>   gaussian blur algorithm” in JavaScript.

http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html
http://badassjs.com/post/1298940200/stackblur

Here are the images that I use to compare it for myself and it was 'close enough' to Flash's BlurFilter that I used it. (StackBlur produces a slightly darker image, *assuming* he is skipping some normalizing that would cause the routine to be slower)

My Air version; quality set to HIGH and x/y filter offset set to 10:
[image]

Here is StackBlur set to a radius of 10:
[image]

Here is the original bitmap:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a near-exact replica of Flash because the application I'm converting is an online drawing application that can record/replay what is drawn in the gallery. If the JavaScript version doesn't blur like the Flash filter did, then the replays will not be accurate and will not look like the final image. Granted, for single-pass blurs on an entire image, it's probably close enough. However, my use-case requires that added precision. :/ Speed is also an issue since it'll be used as a brush stroke.

Comment: Unless Adobe open-sources the Flash player, replicating the exact algorithm is not really going to happen, even tools like their own PhotoShop does not match Flash (PhotoShop does not have to produce a CPU-cycle 'real-time' optimized algorithm). Good Luck